# how to parse pdf in selenium

Tags: pdfbox, pdfparser

I have been trying to read a pdf which is opened in browser. through the following selenium code.

```
    URL pdfURL = new URL(driver.getCurrentUrl());            
    InputStream is = pdfURL.openStream();
    BufferedInputStream fileToParse= new BufferedInputStream(is);
    PDFParser pdfParser=new PDFParser(fileToParse);
    pdfParser.parse(); // getting error here !!!
```

Getting Error:

> java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line`enter code here`

How to get rid of this error?

Comment: Get the latest PDFBox version, make sure your PDF file isn't empty, and really is a PDF, and use current API which is `PDDocument.load(pdfURL.openStream());`.

Comment: I used latest version 2.0.13 and used the below code. Still the same error. Can anyone help.
    URL pdfURL = new URL(driver.getCurrentUrl());
          InputStream is = pdfURL.openStream();
          BufferedInputStream fileToParse= new BufferedInputStream(is);
          PDDocument document= PDDocument.load(fileToParse);//error at this 
          output=new PDFTextStripper().getText(document);

Comment: Please share the file. If you can't share it, save it to a local file to make sure it is not empty. If it isn't empty, make sure it is a Pdf. These start with "%PDF" and a version number. (open it with NOTEPAD++ to look)